# Selenium/ChromeDriver Unknown policy Errors

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently using Python (v3.5.1), Selenium (v3.7), and Chromedriver (v2.33).

When I run the following command:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\ChromeWebdriver\chromedriver.exe')
```

I get the following messages:

```
[2440:4356:1115/112221.822:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(92)] Unknown policy: PasswordManagerAllowShowPasswords
[2440:4356:1115/112221.822:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(92)] Unknown policy: SkipMetadataCheck
[2440:4356:1115/112221.947:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(92)] Unknown policy: PasswordManagerAllowShowPasswords
[2440:4356:1115/112221.947:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(92)] Unknown policy: SkipMetadataCheck
```

The rest of my script works otherwise, but I would like to understand what is causing these errors so that I can make them go away or at least explain why they don't matter to the rest of my team.

Comment: It looks like you have some policies defined. Check `chrome://policy/` to see if it's the case. By default a Chrome doesn't have any.

Comment: It looks like you are right. Those two sit at the bottom of a whole list of policies with an 'unknown policy' status. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this package. it will automatically take chromedriver according to your current browser. Also, update you current google chrome browser if possible. you can install this package by pip.

```
pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller
```

try this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller

chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Also, check the documentation if you needed: https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-autoinstaller/