# Not able to open the UI in Chrome browser with protractor

Tags: proxy, protractor, config

I am getting below mentioned error in the cmd prompt while running the protractor code. 
The browser is starting but not able to open the UI.
I have added a wait and print statement in my test which is executing fine.

```
Z:\user\Projects\Sample>protractor config\protractor.conf.js
(node:6516) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[15:05:37] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[15:05:37] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[9884:6652:0510/150538.243:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(92)] Unknown policy: AlwaysAuthorizePlugins
[9884:6652:0510/150538.244:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(92)] Unknown policy: DisablePluginFinder
[9884:6652:0510/150538.244:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(92)] Unknown policy: DnsPrefetchingEnabled
[9884:6652:0510/150538.324:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(92)] Unknown policy: AlwaysAuthorizePlugins
[9884:6652:0510/150538.324:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(92)] Unknown policy: DisablePluginFinder
[9884:6652:0510/150538.324:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(92)] Unknown policy: DnsPrefetchingEnabled

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12844/devtools/browser/4545c785-9b04-4b0c-b1ce-afbe1be29e99
[6624:1784:0510/150538.477:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(840)] eglInitialize D3D11 failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
Jasmine started
Sleep for 5 secs
Print text: Test1

Executed 0 of 0 specs SUCCESS in 0.004 sec.
[15:05:39] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[15:05:39] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
```

I have deleted the key "1" present under:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>SOFTWARE>Policies>Google>Chrome>ExtensionInstallBlacklist
```

as suggested by one of my colleague. Is this caused due to some company policy/proxy? 
My protractor conf file is:

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:4545/wd/hub",
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    '../e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  chromeDriver: 'C:\\Users\\..\\bin\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\webdriver-manager\\selenium\\chromedriver_2.36.exe',
  capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: {
   binary: process.env.CHROME_BIN
  }
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  beforeLaunch: function() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
  },
  onPrepare() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: check comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47315766/selenium-chromedriver-unknown-policy-errors).  Maybe you have chrome policy set

Comment: I had already checked my chrome policies after seeing this answer but was not sure how to remove the undefined policies as I don't have sufficient privileges. Anyways thanks for replying.

Comment: What's the version of your chrome,  chromedirver_2.36 supports Chrome v63-65